# javascript date serial number

Tags: javascript, numbers, generator

**NB: I cannot use the function Date**

Goal: convert a date, starting from 1st January 1900 to 31st December 2199, in a serial number that varies from 1 to 109573. Returns 0 if the date is invalid.

Examples:

1. dateSerialNumber( 1, 1,1900) returns 1
2. dateSerialNumber(21, 3,2012) returns 40988
3. dateSerialNumber(31,12,2199) returns 109573
4. dateSerialNumber(31,12,1899) returns 0
5. dateSerialNumber(31,13,2000) returns 0
6. dateSerialNumber(29, 2,1991) returns 0

***Some more examples:***
[**Examples of serial number by year**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eiHN.png)

I should also use functions I've already coded:

1. dateValid(intDay, intMonth, intYear)
2. numberDaysInYear(intYear)
3. numberDaysInMonth(intMonth, intYear)

1)

```js
function dateValid(intDay, intMonth, intYear) {
    if ((intYear >= 1900 && intYear <= 2199) && (intMonth >= 1 && intMonth <= 12)
        && (intDay >= 1 && intDay <= numberDaysInMonth(intMonth, intYear))) {
      return true;
    }else return false;

}
```

2)

```js
function numberDaysInYear(intYear) {
   if(bissextile(intYear)) return '366'
   else return '365'
}
```

3)

```js
function numberDaysInMonth(intMonth, intYear) {
   return new Date(intYear, intMonth, 0).getDate();
}
```

Comment: What is the serial number ? Can it change ? If it is based on millisecond it is simpler.

Comment: What is your question about the challenge? Precisely what issue are you having with it? What have you tried so far to solve it?

Comment: @Pred05 It appears to be the number of days since Dec 31, 1899. That date would have a serial number of `0` if it were *valid*.

Comment: For example, 1st Jan 1900 is day 1, 31 Jan 1900 is day 31, 1 Feb 1900 is day 32, 2 Feb 1900 is day 33, etc.

Comment: You can't use Date object ?

Comment: @Pred05 no, as stated above.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!dateValid(intDay, intMonth, intYear))
  return 0

var serialNumber = 0

for (var i = 1900; i < intYear; i++)
  serialNumber += numberDaysInYear(i)

for (var i = 1; i < intMonth; i++)
  serialNumber += numberDaysInMonth(i, intYear)

return serialNumber + intDay
```